# How to press `^|` in Visual Studio on macOS?

Tags: development, visual-studio-code

I want to execute the "Format Document" menu item in Visual Studio on macOS.

I've attempted pressing `control + |` (pipe), but the item is not executed. Can `^|` be interpreted differently than the above key sequence?

[image]

Comment: To type the pipe symbol hold the shift key too. control + shift + |

Answer (score 2):

It could be capital i.

[image]

Try ctrl + Shift + \  if it's not i.

Comment: Found the solution: had to press `ctrl` + `I` (lowercase). Thanks for your hint.